# How can I configure a connection from Bluemix to on-premise database?

Tags: database, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have configured the Secure Gateway service on IBM Bluemix and then the Secure Gateway client in my environment. Both are connected. Thereafter, I added a connection call from my cloud app with the provided `host:port` combination. The app is getting an error `connection refused`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: See my answer below. I have also an example on Github with some step by step instructions https://github.com/data-henrik/Bluemix-onprem-data

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the error is caused by one of the following reasons:

- In the Secure Gateway configuration you have to provide the IP address and port to your on-premises database, as seen from where the Secure Gateway client is running. Did you provide the correct IP address and port number?
- The firewall on your database server is blocking access from the Secure Gateway client.
- The Secure Gateway client needs an ACL (access control list) that opens up connections.
- Your database is not configured to be accessed from outside. Did you open up the port?

Answer (score 0):

```
i changed the db type from DB2 As400 to  normal db2. Now i have this error : 

ERR App [err] com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.DisconnectNonTransientConnectionException: [jcc][t4][2030][11211][4.12.55] A communication error occurred during operations on the connection's underlying socket, socket input stream,
ERR App or socket output stream.  Error location: Reply.fill() - insufficient data (-1).  Message: Insufficient data. ERRORCODE=-4499, SQLSTATE=08001
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:319)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:461)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:456)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.b(z.java:242)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:268)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.c(z.java:381)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.z.v(z.java:1149)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:45)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.n(b.java:1251)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.b(b.java:1123)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.d(b.java:717)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.c(b.java:703)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:391)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.<init>(b.java:320)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:214)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:460)
ERR App [err]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
ERR App [err]   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
ERR App [err]   at wasdev.sample.servlet.DBServlet.getTargetDBConnection(DBServlet.java:136)
ERR App [err]   at wasdev.sample.servlet.DBServlet.doGet(DBServlet.java:57)
ERR App [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
ERR App [err]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
ERR App [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
ERR App [err]   at [internal classes]
ERR App [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
ERR App [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
ERR App [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```